# Meaning of clicking on colored text in Google translator

Tags: google-translate

Please, I want to ask you, what does mean when you try to translate a word in google translator, then you can click on the translated word and chose other translated words with similar meaning. For example, when you translate ride from English to French, you get in translation - balade, promenade, monter, tour, trajet. Balade is the primary word, but when clicking on it, you can choose another one (for example promenade), the text changes colour to orange. I want to know what the clicking on it means. I want to know if I did/submitted something when I clicked on it or it did nothing (maybe I also clicked on button improve this translation - but I did not submit any improve of translation). My point is if I submitted something with my account or not.

Please, answer me only if you are 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

By selecting the alternative word from a list of suggestions the color of the alternative word turns orange only as an "indicator" of the selection for further action (which may be the correction/improvement of "highlighted" translation). In other words, you do not submit anything to Google by only changing the color of translation to orange.

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. So can you ensure me that by my action (highlighting word) nothing happened?

Comment: And nothing happened to my account?

Comment: yes. this is only a visual effect.

Comment: Even when I maybe clicked on - improve this transaction button?

Comment: even then. unless you click on SUBMIT button you do not submit anything

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see your last comment. Can you answer my question again, please: Even when I maybe clicked on - improve this translation button?

Comment: yes, even then. - is the answer

Comment: @StanleyThread https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers